# com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions There are two properties named

Tags: java, jaxb

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "channelType",
    "channelSubType",
    "suffix",
    "userDetail",
    "cardDetail"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "CardCreationRequest")
public class CardCreationRequest extends BaseRequest
    implements Serializable
{

    @XmlElement(required = true, type = Integer.class, nillable = true)
    protected Integer channelType;
    @XmlElement(required = true, type = Integer.class, nillable = true)
    protected Integer channelSubType;

    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String suffix;

    @XmlElement(name="UserDetail", required = true)
    protected UserDetail userDetail;
    @XmlElement(name="CardDetail",required = true)
    protected CardDetail cardDetail;


}
```

---

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "UserDetail", propOrder = {
    "title",
    "lastName",
    "firstName",
    "nickName",
    "dob",
    "addr1",
    "addr2",
    "city",
    "state",
    "county",
    "zip",
    "country",
    "tel",
    "mobtel",
    "telExt",
    "ssn",
    "fein",
    "selfEmployed",
    "middleInitial",
    "mothersmaid",
    "salutation",
    "relation",
    "holderID",
    "others",
    "busNum",
    "busNumExt",
    "faxNum",
    "faxExt",
    "driverlicNum",
    "driverlicState",
    "dependents",
    "fedtaxID",
    "companyName",
    "emerAddr1",
    "emerAddr2",
    "emerCity",
    "emersState",
    "emerZip",
    "emerCounty",
    "emerCountry",
    "emerPhone",
    "emerExt",
    "vip",
    "recipID",
    "pagerNum",
    "maritalStatus",
    "gender",
    "email",
    "language",
    "accessCode",
    "nameOnCard",
    "loginID",
    "itemSrc",
    "birthCity",
    "birthState",
    "hsGradYr",
    "collegeGradYr",
    "maidenName"
    })

public class UserDetail
    implements Serializable
{

    public UserDetail() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String title;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String lastName;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String firstName;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String nickName;
    @XmlElement(name = "DOB", required = true, type = String.class, nillable = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter2 .class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected Date dob;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String addr1;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String addr2;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String city;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String state;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String county;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String zip;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String country;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String tel;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String mobtel;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String telExt;
    @XmlElement(name = "SSN", required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String ssn;
    @XmlElement(name = "FEIN", required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String fein;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String selfEmployed;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String middleInitial;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String mothersmaid;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String salutation;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String relation;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String holderID;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String others;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String busNum;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String busNumExt;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String faxNum;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String faxExt;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String driverlicNum;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String driverlicState;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String dependents;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String fedtaxID;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String companyName;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String emerAddr1;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String emerAddr2;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String emerCity;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String emersState;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String emerZip;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String emerCounty;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String emerCountry;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String emerPhone;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String emerExt;
    @XmlElement(name = "VIP", required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String vip;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String recipID;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String pagerNum;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String maritalStatus;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String gender;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String email;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String language;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String accessCode;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String nameOnCard;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String loginID;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String itemSrc;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String birthCity;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String birthState;
    @XmlElement(name = "HSGradYr", required = true, type = Integer.class, nillable = true)
    protected Integer hsGradYr;
    @XmlElement(name = "CollegeGradYr", required = true, type = Integer.class, nillable = true)
    protected Integer collegeGradYr;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String maidenName;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)




}
```

---

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CardsWS': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1603)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:357)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:246)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:525)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:324)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:474)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:690)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:536)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:205)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:442)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:329)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
There are two properties named "title" 
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.UserDetail.getTitle()
        at wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.UserDetail
        at protected wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.UserDetail wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.CardCreationRequest.userDetail
        at wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.CardCreationRequest
        at private wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.CardCreationRequest wavecrest.orchestration.endpoint.jaxws_asm.CreateCard.arg0
        at wavecrest.orchestration.endpoint.jaxws_asm.CreateCard
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected java.lang.String wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.UserDetail.title
        at wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.UserDetail
        at protected wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.UserDetail wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.CardCreationRequest.userDetail
        at wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.CardCreationRequest
        at private wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.CardCreationRequest wavecrest.orchestration.endpoint.jaxws_asm.CreateCard.arg0
        at wavecrest.orchestration.endpoint.jaxws_asm.CreateCard
Class has two properties of the same name "title"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.UserDetail.getTitle()
        at wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.UserDetail
        at protected wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.UserDetail wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.CardCreationRequest.userDetail
        at wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.CardCreationRequest
        at private wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.CardCreationRequest wavecrest.orchestration.endpoint.jaxws_asm.CreateCard.arg0
        at wavecrest.orchestration.endpoint.jaxws_asm.CreateCard
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected java.lang.String wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.UserDetail.title
        at wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.UserDetail
        at protected wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.UserDetail wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.CardCreationRequest.userDetail
        at wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.CardCreationRequest
        at private wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.CardCreationRequest wavecrest.orchestration.endpoint.jaxws_asm.CreateCard.arg0
        at wavecrest.orchestration.endpoint.jaxws_asm.CreateCard

    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:472)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:363)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:268)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:267)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.createContext(JAXBContextCache.java:266)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:172)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createJAXBContextAndSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:454)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:322)
    ... 46 more
```

Comment: a question would be helpful not just output

Answer (score 15):

This error typically appears when you annotate both the field and the property.  Since you have specified `XmlAccessType.FIELD` you should only annotate the field (instance variable).

You have

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserDetail {

    @XmlElement
    private String title;

    @XmlElement
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

}
```

Change to:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserDetail {

    @XmlElement
    private String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

}
```

This matches what the exception is telling you.  It points to `UserDetail.getTitle()` and `UserDetail.title`.

```
Class has two properties of the same name "title"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.UserDetail.getTitle()
        at wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.UserDetail
        at protected wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.UserDetail wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.CardCreationRequest.userDetail
        at wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.CardCreationRequest
        at private wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.CardCreationRequest wavecrest.orchestration.endpoint.jaxws_asm.CreateCard.arg0
        at wavecrest.orchestration.endpoint.jaxws_asm.CreateCard
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected java.lang.String wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.UserDetail.title
        at wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.UserDetail
        at protected wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.UserDetail wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.CardCreationRequest.userDetail
        at wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.CardCreationRequest
        at private wavecrest.orchestration.cardmanger.dto.CardCreationRequest wavecrest.orchestration.endpoint.jaxws_asm.CreateCard.arg0
        at wavecrest.orchestration.endpoint.jaxws_asm.CreateCard
```

Answer (score 9):

You can find which classes and which methods have problems -along with a detailed message- by debugging **check()**  method of **Builder** inner-class of IllegalAnnotationsException class.

Look at the entries in **list** of IllegalAnnotationsException.

I am using jaxb-impl-2.2.11

Comment: this is what I was looking for!!

Comment: Excellent! But why is the trace not printed?

Comment: simply developer has assumed he has printed enough information. Which is right In most cases :)

Answer (score 1):

Another cause that I've run into is that some of the classes being serialized didn't have no-argument constructors.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24449927)

Comment: I figured anything would be helpful for people running into the same exception. There isn't even a question asked in the original post, but if the question is, "What could cause this exception," then, yes, this is an answer.

Comment: If there is no question in the post, you should comment on the post asking OP to clarify what is the question, instead of putting something in the answer section. So by your logic, this is not an answer sicne there is no question

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another possible reason for this error:

I encountered this problem when I was migrating an operator from our main code to a standalone library that other teams could use. Our design called for the operator to be available from either location from our own project, so I just copy/pasted a whole mess of code into another project and packaged it up into a lib, and then added that lib to the lib directory. However, when I ran it with this configuration, I got this duplicate annotations error. To fix the problem, I just needed to modify the @XmlType name parameter. All I did was just add "Op" to all the annotation names in the library. No other change was required.